# webscraping with rvest, select content in form

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using rvest to web scrape a particular website. On the website I need to select for example the date and the location that I want to display.

```
library(rvest)
session<-html_session(url)
form<-html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]
```

I can now set different values e.g. for the date.

```
set_values(form, from="08.02.2018")
```

and on the console appears: < input text > 'from': 08.02.2018
as well as for the other element "location": < select > 'location': [0/3]
My question is how I can set the value for "location". I know the different elements of "location" from the manual dropdown. Still:

```
set_values(form, location="Location_A")
```

doesn't work. No selection is visible and when submitting the form with

```
result<-submit_form(session,form)
```

A red message is on the console (Submitting with 'Location'). The result is an object with class "session", which I wasnt able to read with

```
html_table(result)
```

With Error: Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "list"
I started with

```
html_table(result[1])
```

However, none was working, same error.

Comment: Can you provide a specific web site? Otherwise, it is very diffcult to provide help.